# Can only connect to Mesos from Spark on the same machine

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am trying to running Spark on a Mesos cluster.

When I run `./bin/spark-shell --master mesos://host:5050` from the machine where I run the Mesos master everything works. However if I run the same command from a different machine, process ends up hanging after trying to connect:

```
I0825 07:30:10.184141 27380 sched.cpp:126] Version: 0.19.0
I0825 07:30:10.187476 27385 sched.cpp:222] New master detected at master@192.168.0.241:5050
I0825 07:30:10.187619 27385 sched.cpp:230] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
```

On the mesos master I see the following output:

```
[...]
I0825 15:30:23.928402 23214 master.cpp:684] Giving framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002 0ns to failover
I0825 15:30:23.929033 23210 master.cpp:2849] Framework failover timeout, removing framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:23.929095 23210 master.cpp:3344] Removing framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:23.929687 23210 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:636] Recovered mem(*):512 (total allocatable: cpus(*):4; mem(*):6831; disk(*):455983; ports(*):[31000-32000]) on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31 from framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:23.935073 23210 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:636] Recovered mem(*):512 (total allocatable: cpus(*):4; mem(*):15001; disk(*):917264; ports(*):[31000-32000]) on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-29 from framework   20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:23.938248 23210 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:636] Recovered mem(*):512 (total allocatable: mem(*):6823; disk(*):455991; ports(*):[31000-32000]; cpus(*):4) on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-32 from framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:23.938356 23210 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:636] Recovered mem(*):512 (total allocatable: mem(*):4939; disk(*):457873; ports(*):[31000-32000]; cpus(*):4) on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-28 from framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:23.938397 23210 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:362] Removed framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:27.952940 23215 http.cpp:452] HTTP request for '/master/state.json'
W0825 15:30:29.595441 23208 master.cpp:2718] Ignoring unknown exited executor 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-32 on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-32 at slave(1)@192.168.0.233:5051 (cluster2)
W0825 15:30:29.596709 23213 master.cpp:2718] Ignoring unknown exited executor 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-29 on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-29 at slave(1)@192.168.0.241:5051 (cluster4)
W0825 15:30:29.615630 23213 master.cpp:2718] Ignoring unknown exited executor 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31 on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31 at slave(1)@192.168.0.213:5051 (cluster3)
W0825 15:30:29.935130 23214 master.cpp:2718] Ignoring unknown exited executor 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-28 on slave 20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-28 at slave(1)@192.168.0.212:5051 (cluster1)
```

Where as the slaves output

```
[...]
I0825 15:30:08.450343   980 slave.cpp:1337] Asked to shut down framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002 by master@192.168.0.241:5050
I0825 15:30:08.455153   980 slave.cpp:1362] Shutting down framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:08.455401   980 slave.cpp:2698] Shutting down executor '20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31' of framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:13.456045   982 slave.cpp:2768] Killing executor '20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31' of framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:13.456217   982 mesos_containerizer.cpp:992] Destroying container '37cc2b09-0e6d-4738-a837-7956367bba2b'
I0825 15:30:14.134845   977 mesos_containerizer.cpp:1108] Executor for container '37cc2b09-0e6d-4738-a837-7956367bba2b' has exited
I0825 15:30:14.135220   978 slave.cpp:2413] Executor '20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31' of framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002 has terminated with signal Killed
I0825 15:30:14.135356   978 slave.cpp:2552] Cleaning up executor '20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31' of framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:14.135499   978 slave.cpp:2627] Cleaning up framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:14.135627   976 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework 20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002
I0825 15:30:14.135571   975 gc.cpp:56] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31/frameworks/20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002/executors/20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31/runs/37cc2b09-0e6d-4738-a837-7956367bba2b' for gc 6.99999843242074days in the future
I0825 15:30:14.135910   975 gc.cpp:56] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31/frameworks/20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002/executors/20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31' for gc 6.99999843187556days in the future
I0825 15:30:14.135980   975 gc.cpp:56] Scheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20140822-144404-4043352256-5050-15999-31/frameworks/20140825-143817-4043352256-5050-23194-0002' for gc 6.99999843111111days in the future
I0825 15:31:04.450660   978 slave.cpp:2873] Current usage 60.67%. Max allowed age: 2.053113079446458days
```

Have anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Can you give more details about your machine and networking configuration? Are `mesos-master` and `mesos-slave` running on the same machine? Is port 5050 on the master's machine accessible from the machine where you're trying to run Spark? If you're running multiple masters, you'll need ZooKeeper.

Comment: I am having the same issue right now testing on local VMs. I am able to telnet to the mesos-master port 5050 from a different box. I only have one mesos-master and zookeeper is running on the same instance. mesos-slave is running in different VM.

Comment: I just tested moving everything to EC2 and it worked fine so I guess its a problem with the local VMs network. Its weird because I am able to telnet between them in port 5050.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused not by network connectivity issues but by Mesos slave recovery policy as outlined here: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/slave-recovery/

I would initially connect slaves to the master and disconnect them because of an unrelated problem, however when I later tried to connect the slaves again, they were being dropped by the master. To quote the documentation linked above:

> A restarted slave should re-register with master within a timeout (currently, 75s). If the slave takes longer than this timeout to re-register, the master shuts down the slave, which in turn shuts down any live executors/tasks. Therefore, it is highly recommended to automate the process of restarting a slave (e.g, using monit).

I solved the problem by connecting the slaves with the `--strict` option set to `false`.