# Spark on Mesos Cluster - Task Fails

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mesos

I'm trying to run a Spark application in a Mesos cluster where I have one master and one slave. The slave has 8GB RAM assigned for Mesos. The master is running the Spark Mesos Dispatcher.

I use the following command to submit a Spark application (which is a streaming application).

```
spark-submit --master mesos://mesos-master:7077 --class com.verifone.media.ums.scheduling.spark.SparkBootstrapper --deploy-mode cluster scheduling-spark-0.5.jar
```

And I see the following output which shows its successfully submitted.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/09/01 12:52:38 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in mesos://mesos-master:7077.
15/09/01 12:52:39 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submission successfully created as driver-20150901072239-0002. Polling submission state...
15/09/01 12:52:39 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20150901072239-0002 in mesos://mesos-master:7077.
15/09/01 12:52:39 INFO RestSubmissionClient: State of driver driver-20150901072239-0002 is now QUEUED.
15/09/01 12:52:40 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Server responded with CreateSubmissionResponse:
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.4.1",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20150901072239-0002",
  "success" : true
}
```

However, this fails in Mesos, and when I look at the Spark Cluster UI, I see the following message.

```
task_id { value: "driver-20150901070957-0001" } state: TASK_FAILED message: "" slave_id { value: "20150831-082639-167881920-5050-4116-S6" } timestamp: 1.441091399975446E9 source: SOURCE_SLAVE reason: REASON_MEMORY_LIMIT 11: "\305-^E\377)N\327\277\361:\351\fm\215\312"
```

Seems like it is related to memory, but I'm not sure whether I have to configure something here to get this working.

**UPDATE**
I looked at the mesos logs in the slave, and I see the following message.

```
E0901 07:56:26.086618  1284 fetcher.cpp:515] Failed to run mesos-fetcher: Failed to fetch all URIs for container '33183181-e91b-4012-9e21-baa37485e755' with exit status: 256
```

So I thought that this could be because of the Spark Executor URL, so I modified the spark-submit to be as follows and increased memory for both driver and slave, but still I see the same error.

```
spark-submit \
    --master mesos://mesos-master:7077 \
    --class com.verifone.media.ums.scheduling.spark.SparkBootstrapper \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 1G \
    --executor-memory 4G \
    --conf spark.executor.uri=http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz \
    scheduling-spark-0.5.jar
```

**UPDATE 2**

I went past this point by following @hartem's advice (see comments). Tasks are running now, but still, actual Spark application does not run in the cluster. When I look at the logs I see the following. After the last line, seems that Spark does not proceed any further.

```
15/09/01 10:33:41 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150831-082639-167881920-5050-4116-S8/frameworks/20150831-082639-167881920-5050-4116-0004/executors/driver-20150901103327-0002/runs/47339c12-fb78-43d6-bc8a-958dd94d0ccf/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/../scheduling-spark-0.5.jar at http://192.172.1.31:33666/jars/scheduling-spark-0.5.jar with timestamp 1441103621639
I0901 10:33:41.728466  4375 sched.cpp:157] Version: 0.23.0
I0901 10:33:41.730764  4383 sched.cpp:254] New master detected at master@192.172.1.10:7077
I0901 10:33:41.730908  4383 sched.cpp:264] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
```

Comment: Could you please do `export GLOG_v=1` before launching the slave and see if there is anything interesting in the slave log? I would also look for `stdout` and `stderr` files under the slave working directory and see if they contain any clues.

Comment: Thanks @hartem. I looked into the stdout and stderr in disk (these weren't accessible from Mesos UI because of Internal IPs) and found that it actually fails when it tries to download my application JAR (I was submitting the local path). When I provided it as a HTTP URL it worked. Please post your response as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @hartem Please see Update 2. I got past the initial issue with your help. However, now the Spark application seems to be stuck before it actually starts processing. Both master and slave can see each other (verified through telnet).

Comment: Thanks! I would suggest posting a follow-up issue as a separate question.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481282/can-only-connect-to-mesos-from-spark-on-the-same-machine) first, it might solve your follow up problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please do export GLOG_v=1 before launching the slave and see if there is anything interesting in the slave log? I would also look for stdout and stderr files under the slave working directory and see if they contain any clues.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue problem was slave could not find the required jar for running the class file(SparkPi). So i gave the http URL of the jar it worked, it requires jar to be placed in distributed system not on local file system.

```
/home/centos/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit \
  --name SparkPiTestApp \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master mesos://xxxxxxx:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 30 \
  http://downloads.mesosphere.com.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/spark/spark-examples_2.10-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 100
```